# Authentication with 'before_filter'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, before-filter

I'm trying to figure out `before_filters` and I was hoping for a little help.

I have a simple blog app, with entries that can be (draft or published) and (public or private).  I was wondering how I can do my authentication?

I currently have:

`before_filter :authenticate, :except => [ :show ]`

So that blocks all the CRUD actions.  For `show`, I need to check that:

1. If its a draft, that the logged in user owns the entry.
2. If its private, a user is logged in (in this, all logged in users can see private entries)

I can do it within the action itself, but it seems that the *rails* way of doing it, is in a `before_filter`.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use something like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) that will let you write up a set of rules for each entry and then just apply them to the actions. It will be much cleaner to read.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I did end up using CanCan.  I had heard about it, but didn't realize how indepth it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in the before filter.  If you are using devise then the current_user method is available if a user is logged in.  Otherwise replace current_user with the value returned from your authenticate method.

```
def find_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_path if @post.draft && @post.user != current_user
  redirect_to root_path if @post.private && !current_user
end
```

Comment: Is it good practice to put this type of logic in the model? or keep it in the controller because it has to do with whether to show the action or not?